# Ember data JSONAPIAdapter: fetch nested resources

Tags: javascript, django, ember.js, django-rest-framework, ember-data

I'm trying to get Ember Data's JSONAPIAdapter to work with nested resources. For the server part django-rest-framework-json-api is used.

My (simplified) ember models:

*case.js*

```
export default Model.extend({
  firstName: attr('string'),
  lastName: attr('string'),
  comments: hasMany('comment'),
})
```

*comment.js*

```
export default Model.extend({
  text: attr('string'),
  case: belongsTo('case'),
})
```

The server's response for `/api/v1/cases/4` looks like this:

```
{
  "data": [
    {
      "type": "cases",
      "id": "4",
      "attributes": {
         "first-name": "Hans",
         "last-name": "Peter",
      },
      "relationships": {
        "comments": {
          "meta": {
            "count": 1
          },
          "data": [
            {
              "type": "comments",
              "id": "5"
            }
          ],
          "links": {
            "related": "http://localhost:8000/api/v1/cases/4/comments"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Now, if i understand Ember Data and the JSON-API spec correctly, ember should request `/api/v1/cases/4/comments` when i reference the comments. Instead, it requests `/api/v1/comments/5`, which obviously returns a `404`.

My questions in summary:

- Does the server response comply to the JSON-API spec?
- How do i get ember to respect the nested route?

I'm using ember v2.8.

Bonus question: I face the same problem for creating a new comment - how do i get ember to `POST` to `/case/4/comments` instead of `/comments`?

Comment: Yes this works and your json looks correct how do you "reference the comments"? Also my posts are to the comments resources directly.

Comment: Currently, i just access `model.comments` in a template. According to the feedback from the ember community slack on this issue there are some subtleties related to how one accesses the resource - do you know more about this?

Comment: Assuming your model is an instance of "case" this looks correct. I have done this using firebase and loopback. Not sure about the "subtleties". I will  add an answer with a json sample and a code sample if you like.

Comment: That would definitely be interesting. I will also try to reproduce the issue in a minimal setup.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The JSON API spec does not enforce any specific URL pattern, so what you're trying to do is compliant. However, I find that working with a flat URL structure is easier with Ember Data, though there is a workaround.

You'll want to look at the [ember-data-url-templates](https://github.com/amiel/ember-data-url-templates) addon and add some logic from it to your model's adapter.

With that addon, here is what you can do with `app/adapters/comment.js`:

```
import ApplicationAdapter from './application';
import UrlTemplates from 'ember-data-url-templates';

export default ApplicationAdapter.extend(UrlTemplates, {
  namespace: 'api/v1', // You may or may not need this namespace setting:
                       // I'm a little rusty in this area :)

  urlTemplate: '{+host}/case/{caseId}/comments{/id}',

  urlSegments: {
    contentId: function(type, id, snapshot/*, query */) {
      return snapshot.belongsTo('case', { id: true });
    }
  }
});
```

Unless there is something else that the addon allows to get around this, I believe that this then locks you into that URL structure for comments across your entire app. So definitely weigh that tradeoff before deciding to go down this route.

Comment: Since ember-data currently doesn't support following the `related` links for `POST` or `PATCH` requests, this seems to be the way to go if flattening URLs is not an option - thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Yes this works it should be setup as follows

models/client.js

```
export default DS.Model.extend({
    name: DS.attr('string'),
    telno: DS.attr('string'),

    campaigns: hasMany()
});
```

models/client.js

```
export default DS.Model.extend({
    name: DS.attr('string'),
    startdate: DS.attr('date'),
    enddate: DS.attr('date'),

    client: DS.belongsTo('client')
});
```

/templates/client/edit.bhs

```html
    <table class="table table-bordered table-striped table-condensed">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th></th>
                <th>Name</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            {{#each model.campaigns as |campaign|}}
                <tr>
                    <td>{{campaign.name}}</td>
                </tr>
            {{/each}}
        </tbody>
    </table>
```

http://localhost:3000/api/clients/1

```
{
{
  "links": {
    "self": "http://localhost:3000/api/clients/1"
  },
  "data": {
    "type": "clients",
    "relationships": {
      "campaigns": {
        "links": {
          "related": "http://localhost:3000/api/clients/1/campaigns"
        }
      }
    },
    "id": "1",
    "attributes": {
      "name": "Test",
      "telno": "123"
    },
    "links": {
      "self": "http://localhost:3000/api/clients/1"
    }
  }
}
```

http://localhost:3000/api/clients/1/campaigns

```
{
  "links": {
    "self": "http://localhost:3000/api/clients/1/campaigns"
  },
  "data": [
    {
      "type": "campaigns",
      "relationships": {
        "client": {
          "links": {
            "related": "http://localhost:3000/api/campaigns/1/client"
          }
        }
      },
      "id": "1",
      "attributes": {
        "enddate": "2019-01-01T00:00:00.000Z",
        "name": "test",
        "startdate": null
      },
      "links": {
        "self": "http://localhost:3000/api/campaigns/1"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: We decided to go with the `ember-data-url-templates` approach because we need to call the nested route for `POST` and `PATCH`, too (see my comment above). Thank you for posting this anyway, i'll try this approach next time when i only need `GET`!